# How do I load two different layouts inside a table view cell in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have two prototype cells, both with different layouts. The reason for this is one cell will load males and one cell will load females. I have gave both cells an identifier and now am trying to load into each cell there relevant content. When I load the code it only loads into prototype cell 1.

This is the code I am using inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 let cellFemale : Profiles = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellFemale") as Profiles
 let cellMale : Profiles = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellMale") as Profiles

   if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female" {
        //Adding the textLabel
       cellFemale.nameLabel?.text = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]

        //Adding the profile picture
        var finalImage = UIImage(data: self.profile.images[indexPath.row])
        cellFemale.imageLabel?.image = finalImage

        //Adding the gender label
        //if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female"{
        cellFemale.genderLabel.text = "F"
        } else if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "male" {

            //Adding the textLabel
            cellMale.nameLabel?.text = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]

            //Adding the profile picture
            var finalImage = UIImage(data: self.profile.images[indexPath.row])
            cellMale.imageLabel?.image = finalImage

            //Adding the gender label
            //if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female"{
            cellMale.genderLabel.text = "M"
        }
```

---

I did forget to add cellMale as a return value. but now I am getting that: (Profiles, Profiles) is not convertible to UITableViewCell. Full code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellFemale : Profiles = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellFemale") as Profiles
        let cellMale : Profiles = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellMale") as Profiles

  if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female" {
        //Adding the textLabel
       cellFemale.nameLabel?.text = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]

        //Adding the profile picture
        var finalImage = UIImage(data: self.profile.images[indexPath.row])
        cellFemale.imageLabel?.image = finalImage

        //Adding the gender label
        //if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female"{
        cellFemale.genderLabel.text = "F"
        } else if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "male" {

            //Adding the textLabel
            cellMale.nameLabel?.text = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]

            //Adding the profile picture
            var finalImage = UIImage(data: self.profile.images[indexPath.row])
            cellMale.imageLabel?.image = finalImage

            //Adding the gender label
            //if self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "female"{
            cellMale.genderLabel.text = "M"
        }



        return (cellFemale, cellMale)
    }
```

Comment: Are you returning the correct cell at the end of the function?

Comment: Please post the **complete** `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to dequeue the type of cell that you will be using for this row.  Also, much of your code is repeated between the male and female cases.  I suggest:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let isMale = (self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "male")
    let identifier = isMale ? "cellMale" : "cellFemale"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as Profiles

    cell.nameLabel?.text = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]

    //Adding the profile picture
    let finalImage = UIImage(data: self.profile.images[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageLabel?.image = finalImage

    //Adding the gender label
    cell.genderLabel.text = isMale ? "M" : "F"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer it helped a lot and got what I wanted which is males and females separated by having one gender on the left and one on the right. Although your answer only allows me to access one one of the genders? If it is set to: `let isMale = (self.profile.genders[indexPath.row] == "male")` I can only access the females? Can you you help a bit more please?

Comment: `isMale` is a `Bool` that is `true` for males, and `false` for females.  This gets set for each table row, which allows one cell to be male and the next female. That is used to choose the `identifier` to dequeue the proper prototype cell for that row.  Can you describe your difficulty in more detail?  What are you seeing?

Comment: When I tap the cellForRowAtIndexPath it only segues to the next VC on one of the genders. I want it to work as a normal argue with every cell but still having the genders split left and right?

Comment: Do you have 2 different detail views (one for male, one for female) or are the layouts of the detail view the same?

Comment: You need to set up a segue from each of your 2 prototype cells to their detail view.

Comment: Thanks this sorted it! Thanks again!